# RemoveAt(index) remove every alternate item in menu not the one that are indexed

Tags: asp.net, menu, menuitem

I have a menu and I am disabling certain options for certain group. It is dropdown menu with about 10 entriees. When I run code like this

```
menuMain.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(0);
menuMain.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(1);
menuMain.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(2);
menuMain.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(3);
menuMain.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(4);
menuMain.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(5);
```

which means I want to remove first 6 entries for this one group, I get exception at item no 5, saying the index is out of range.

I found the above code removes every other item from menu, not the one that are referenced.

```
removes 0th item
removes 2nd item
removes 4rd item
...
removes 10th item
removes 12th item (index not found)
```

Does anyone know why it is behaving like this?

Note: I checked the code in debug mode and it does points to correct menuitem that is both odd and even and it does not jump by 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - imagine you initially have items `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]`.

Now you call `RemoveAt(0)`. That removes the first item (`a`), leaving you with `[b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]`.

Now you call `RemoveAt(1)`. That removes the *second remaining* item (`c`), leaving you with `[b, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]`.

Now you call `RemoveAt(2)`. That removes the *third remaining* item (`e`), leaving you with:
`[b, d, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]`.

... etc

The problem is that you're thinking of the indexes in the *original* list - not after the "removals so far". If you want to remove the first 6 entries, you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    menuMain.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: You are genius! what's the cure though, I can just use `menuMain.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(0);` 5 times and it will remove first 5 entries. Any better solution?

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: You might want to look for something like `RemoveRange` - it depends on the type returned from `ChildItems`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thanks!

Comment: One word: Genius! Helped me sort my problem which took ages to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you remove the first element (childItem) at index 0 the second element (index 1) takes its place at index 0.

Try removing them in a reversed order.

```
menuMain.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(5);
menuMain.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(4);
```

Comment: +1 another great answer. In my actual problem I had to remove about 20 items so I used loop approach.

Answer (score 1):

Start from 5 down to 0. When you remove item 0 the item that was at place 1 moves to place 0, so the next remove call removes the second item.